# What does “unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'tuple'” means?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i got a error saing: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'tuple'

```
    def accounting(self):
        [total], = self.db.c.execute('''SELECT NeedInvestment FROM building WHERE id == 5''')

        investment = []
        for i in self.db.c.execute('''SELECT AmountOfInvestment FROM investor '''):
            investment.append(i)

        totaltemp = 0

        while totaltemp <= total:
            i = random.randint(0, 5)
            totaltemp += investment[1]
```

How do i correct it?

Comment: and how to convert to int?
Yes i is the element index later

Answer (score 1):

```
self.db.c.execute('''SELECT AmountOfInvestment FROM investor ''')
```

this returns a `list` of `tuple` objects.

```
totaltemp += investment[1]
```

`investment[1]` is the second tuple in the list. It's a tuple. `totalTemp` is an `int` as declared here:

```
totalTemp = 0
```

So you're trying to add a `tuple` to an `int` - which is not defined in the python language.

You probably want to access a value inside the tuple like this:

```
totalTemp = investment[0][1]
```

Comment: now i get the error: totaltemp = investment[0][1]
IndexError: tuple index out of range. 
I also need to summarize the totalTemp in a loop.

Comment: Check `investment`. It's probably not what you expect it to be,